# Option element accesskey

Tags: html

In [**HTML5**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#the-accesskey-attribute):

> All HTML elements may have the accesskey content attribute set.

IE and Firefox do not support `accesskey` on an `option` element, but Chrome, Safari, and Opera do.

However, support seems bizarre.

Given this HTML:

```
<select>
  <option accesskey="A" value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
  <option accesskey="B" value="Baked" >Baked</option>
</select>
```

… pressing <kbd>Alt+B</kbd> focuses and highlights the "Baked" option.

However, pressing <kbd>Alt+B</kbd> again causes the `select` box to be blank and to have *no value* – even though it has no empty `option` elements.

What's stranger is that even though the `select` value changes, a change event is not triggered *unless* you press <kbd>Alt+B</kbd> repeatedly.

What's going on?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fun26o7q/)